# Sistema de versionamento de arquivos

Tags: javascript, html

Ola pessoal fiz um codigo simples em JavaScript para atualizar o cache da pagina
Segue o codigo:

```js
//sistema de versionamento de arquivos
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999999 + 1000000) //gera um numero aleatorio entre 1000000 e 999999999

    //css
    document.getElementById("css").href = "css/browse.css?v=" + number;

    //js
    document.getElementById("js").src = "js/browse.js?v=" + number;

    //blocks
    document.getElementById("lastadded").src = "blocks/lastadded.html?v=" + number;
    document.getElementById("movies").src = "blocks/movies.html?v=" + number;
    document.getElementById("series").src = "blocks/series.html?v=" + number;
    document.getElementById("animes").src = "blocks/animes.html?v=" + number;
```

nao sei o que esta acontecendo, mas a parte blocks nao funciona. esse codigo esta dentro do js/browse.js.
Alguem explica o que esta errado, ou tem uma maneira melhor de lidar com esse problema de cache?

Comment: Essa parte de "blocks" são iframes?

Comment: @Sam sim sao iframes

Comment: Vc diz que não funciona. O Que não funciona? Ele não atualiza o cache ou não carrega as páginas no iframe?

Comment: @Sam e conseguir resolver a parte dos iframes, mas eu quero uma forma mais pratica de atualizar o arquivos html, css, js...

Comment: Ao meu ver a forma mais prática é o que está fazendo, gerando um número aleatório e adicionando no caminho dos arquivos.

Comment: ah ok, obrigado pela atençao